# Why must there be an infinite number of lines in an absolute geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history, noneuclidean-geometry

Why must there be an infinite number of lines in an absolute geometry? I see that there must be an infinite number of points pretty trivially due to the protractor postulate, and there are an infinite number of real numbers. Hence, theres an infinite number of points, but why must there be an infinite number of lines? Does it follow from the existence axiom where two distinct points completely determine the existence of a line between these two points?

Comment: Precisely what axioms are you assuming? Does one of them imply the existence of noncollinear points?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the Euclidean axioms.

Comment: As far as I understand it absolute geometry rejects Euclid's 5th postulate of parallel lines. So we have the other four incidence axioms, 1. every pair of distinct points determines a line 2, three non collinear points determine a plane, 3. if two points lie in a plane then any line containing them is in the plane 4. if distinct planes meet their intersection is a line

Comment: Bit confused about how these four incidence axioms implies infinitely many lines

Comment: See my answer for a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Pick one point $P$. Through $P$ and each other point $Q$ there's a line, $\ell_Q$, by axiom 1.

Case 1: There are infinitely many $\ell_Q$, and we're done.

Case 2: There are finitely many lines $\ell_X$. In that case, one of them -- say $\ell_Q$ -- must contain infinitely many points $R_1, R_2, \ldots$. (Because we know that the geometry has infinitely many points, and each point $X \ne P$ is on $\ell_X$.) Now let $S$ be a point not on $\ell_Q$. Then the lines $SR_i$ are all distinct. (For if $SR_1$ and $SR_2$ shared a point $R_k$ for some $k \ne 1, 2$, we'd have $R_1$ and $R_k$ on both $SR_1$ and on $\ell_Q$, a contradiction.) Hence in this case there are infinitely many lines as well.

Comment: Ah thank you that makes much more sense now

Comment: How do we know there is an infinite amount of points?

Comment: How do we know there is a point not on $l_Q$?

Comment: It seems to me that you can simplify the reasoning by omitting Case 1 altogether. Thus: "[for all $Q$] there's a line, $\ell_Q$, by axiom 1. One of them — say $\ell_X$ — must contain [*etc.*]"

Comment: The OP said that the existence of an infinite number of points was known/understood to him, so I didn't bother saying anything about that. There's a point not on $\ell_q$ because not all points are collinear (at least I'm assuming that's one of the axioms, because otherwise it's not an interesting geometry).

Comment: Theophile: its at least imaginable to me that there's a point $P$ and for each other point $Q$, there's a line $PQ$ containing $P$ and $Q$ and no other points. At that point, I don't have infinitely many points on one line (although I do have infinitely many lines). You're probably right that there's a way to simplify, but I just wanted to write down *an* answer, not the best possible. Some days we set our sights lower...